# delete igraph vertices but retain all edges in R

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a way to delete (or selectively display) vertices but retain edges in an igraph plot? For example, in the code below, we delete vertices but that deletes edges between them. My goal is to highlight a specific node but keep all edges.

```
g <- make_ring(10) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("name", value = LETTERS[1:10])
g
V(g)

g2 <- delete_vertices(g, c(1,5)) %>%
  delete_vertices("B")
g2
V(g2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the vertices, the edges no longer make any sense. However, if all you want is to not *display* the vertices, you can just use `vertex.size=0`.

```
plot(g, vertex.size=0)
```

[image: Nodes not displayed.]

If you do not want to even see the node names,  add `vertex.label=NA`

You can show just one node by making a vector of vertex sizes and labels

```
VS = rep(0, vcount(g))
VS[2] = 14
VL = rep(NA, vcount(g))
VL[2] = V(g)$name[2]

VFC = rep(NA, vcount(g))
VFC[2] = "black"
VC = rep(NA, vcount(g))
VC[2] = 1

plot(g, vertex.size=VS, vertex.label=VL, vertex.color=VC,
    vertex.frame.color=VFC)
```

[image: Just one node]

Comment: is there a specific way to selectively plot vertices?, that is just display the vertex and label for B?

Comment: Yes,  I will add to the answer.

Comment: Perfect answer, but is there a way to make the other vertices not show up at all?

Comment: Enhanced previous answer. Got rid of minor traces of other nodes.